# Filtering regressions tests via Docker for CodeFresh

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, xunit, codefresh

I have a C#/Selenium/Xunit test suite which is running on CodeFresh. The project works well with both the build and run pipelines performing as expect except for one thing, filtering.

So in the Test Project we have a set of warmup tests I want to run separately before the main run pipeline.
Now in the feature file these have the tag - `@warmup`
In the hooks file this is shown as `[Scope(Tag = "warmup")]` and the filtering works fine when run from VS or a batch file.

For CodeFresh I have the line in the Docker file thus -

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "/app/BackOffice_Automation.dll", "-v", "n", "--filter", "Category=warmup"]
```

But this is always ignore and all of the tests run, can anyone explain what I have missed please

Thanks

Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, yaml files
This is from the warmup yaml

entry_point: ["dotnet", "test", "/app/BackOffice_Automation.dll", "-v", "n", "--filter", "Category=warmup"]